# Remove one of some possible substrings from the middle of a string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

i have some for loop with some strings from which i would like to remove any of `_win64|_win32|_x64|_x86` and `.dll` at the end and all that lowercase

```
from re import match, sub, compile, escape, IGNORECASE, MULTILINE
filename = filename_without_extension.lower()
print("filename {}".format(filename))
pattern = compile("^(?:.*)(_win64|_win32|_x64|_x86)\.dll$", IGNORECASE|MULTILINE)
for dll in p.memory_maps():
    file = dll.path.lower().rsplit('\\', 1)[1]
    if not file.endswith(".dll") and not file.endswith(".DLL"): continue # TODO: Remove
    print("file: {}".format(file))
    print("pattern: {}".format(pattern.sub("", file)))
    if pattern.sub("", file).endswith(filename): return AddonStatus.LOADED
```

Why does this feel so hard in regex?

EDIT: Some example strings that would be inside the `file` variable:
`test.dll`
`test_win32.DLL`
`test_WIN64.dLL`
`test_X86.dll`
`test_x64.DLL`

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Could you provide some sample strings that you are trying to parse?

Comment: @Saud i added some examples :)

Comment: Are you after something like https://ideone.com/vKmioR?

Comment: How about this: `^(?:.*)(_win64|_win32|_x64|_x86)?\.dll$`
 This matches all the sample strings that you have provided. (Btw, I have just added a `?` after  `x86)`)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew more like https://ideone.com/F44evY

Comment: @Saud this also removes everything not just the _XXX.dll part

Comment: btw the full code is at https://github.com/Bluscream/pyTSon_plugins/blob/master/include/bluscream.py#L427

Comment: @Bluscream `(_win64|_win32|_x64|_x86)?\.dll\b`, simply use this, then. It only deletes the _XXX.dll part

Comment: that one still doesn't find it, sadly :(

Comment: So, my code almost worked, you needed `re.sub` instead of `re.search`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lst= ['test.dll',
'test_win32.DLL',
'test_WIN64.dLL',
'test_X86.dll',
'test_x64.DLL']

import re

to_remove = ('_win64', '_win32', '_x64', '_x86')
r = re.compile(r'({})\.dll$'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, to_remove))), flags=re.I)

for l in lst:
    print(r.sub(r'', l).lower().rstrip('.dll'))
```

This will strip all the suffixes + .dll:

```
test
test
test
test
test
```

Answer (score 0):

For now i am gonna use

```
file = dll.path.lower().rsplit('\\', 1)[1].replace("_win64","").replace("_win32","").replace("_x86","").replace("_x64","").replace(".DLL","").replace(".dll","")
```

If you have a better solution feel free to share it :)